# Join Dataframes in Pandas and Sum Columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Lets say I have 2 dataframes in pandas. I want to perform a left join on these dataframes in a very specific way as follows, and the easiest way to explain is probably via an example.

First dataframe:

Date   Col1   Col2
1/1
2/1
...

Second Dataframe:

Date    A   B    C
1/1     90  0    0
1/1      0   75  0
1/1     73  0   0
2/1     0    0   85
2/1     0    0   75

The dates in the first dataframe are unique and will be used to join to the second dataframe. Col1 and Col2 are not blank, but they are irrelevant for what I want to do. In second data frame, a date can appear multiple times, and exactly one of the columns A, B, and C contain a number greater than 0, with the other two containing 0. There could also be some extra columns which are irrelevant for what I want to do.

I want to keep everything in the first dataframe and add columns A, B and C in such a way that the values in those columns would be the sum of all values on the given data in the second dataframe. So in the example above, I would want the output to look like this:

Date   Col1   Col2     A   B    C
1/1                       163 75   0
2/1                           0   0   160
...

I have looked at the pandas join function but it doesn't seem to give the option to sum columns in the way that I want. Is there any other way to achieve such a result? I realise I could probably write a for loop to do this, but I was hoping there might be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `groupby` sum on df1, and `merge` the result with `df0`:

```
In [127]: df1.groupby("Date", as_index=False).sum()
Out[127]: 
  Date    A   B    C
0  1/1  163  75    0
1  2/1    0   0  160

In [128]: df0.merge(df1.groupby("Date", as_index=False).sum())
Out[128]: 
  Date  Col1  Col2    A   B    C
0  1/1   NaN   NaN  163  75    0
1  2/1   NaN   NaN    0   0  160
```

(I'm assuming here that Date is a column, and not an index, but it's easy to either `reset_index()` or use `level=0` instead.)

Comment: Thank you. Date is indeed a column. I've another question in relation to performing the groupby operation. If there are other (non-numeric) columns in the dataframe (df1 in this case), but the values in these columns is the same if the date is the same, is it possible to sum the columns A, B, C as before, but just take the first (for example) value in the extra columns. Summing these columns just results in the same string being repeated multiple times. Or would it just be better to group by multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2], 'Col2': [3, 4]}, index=['1/1', '2/1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [90, 0, 73, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 75, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 85, 75]}, index=['1/1', '1/1', '1/1', '2/1', '2/1'])
```

The dataframes `df1` and `df2` are as in your post. To "join" the dataframes the way you want, you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.groupby(level=0).sum()], axis=1)
```

Here, `df` is:

```
     Col1  Col2  A   B    C
1/1  1     3     163 75   0
2/1  2     4     0   0    160
```

Note that this also works if the index of the two dataframes `df1` and `df2` are not aligned. With:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3], 'Col2': [3, 4, 5]}, index=['1/1', '2/1', '4/1'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [90, 0, 73, 0, 0, 20], 'B': [0, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 85, 75, 0]}, index=['1/1', '1/1', '2/1', '3/1', '4/1', '4/1'])
```

and, again:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.groupby(level=0).sum()], axis=1, sort=True)
```

is given by:

```
     Col1  Col2  A   B   C
1/1  1.0   3.0   90  75  0
2/1  2.0   4.0   73  0   0
3/1  NaN   NaN   0   0   85
4/1  3.0   5.0   20  0   75
```